# About completeness of the Fourier series.

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The Fourier series of a function is given by $$ \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos n \theta +  \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin n \theta . $$ Here what does the statement " $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin n \theta $  is complete"  mean? And would you tell me how can I prove this statement?

Comment: Where did you see this sentence? In which context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it makes sense to call a Fourier series complete.

But what you can call complete is the basis of your space.

For example, if the functions you're computing Fourier series of are in $L^2(G)$, where $G$ is a compact Abelian topological group, one can say that the characters $\chi$ of $G$ are complete and it means two things:

(i) that for every function $f$ in $L^2$ there exists a sequence of continuous characters $\chi_n \in \mathrm{Hom}(G, S^1)$ such that $\|f - \sum_{k=0}^n a_k \chi_k \|_{L^2} \xrightarrow{n \to \infty} 0$ and

(ii) that $\chi_n$ are orthonormal, that is, $\langle \chi_n , \chi_m \rangle = \delta_{nm}$ where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the inner product of $L^2$, namely, $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_G f \;\overline{g}\; d \mu$ (where $\overline{g}$ denotes complex conjugation)

Comment: To be more concrete: if your group is for example $G = \mathbb R / \mathbb Z$ then your characters are $\chi_n (x) = e^{i 2 \pi n x}$. To prove that these are orthonormal is not too difficult, it's a matter of integration by parts. On the other hand, proving claim (i) is rather involved as far as I know but I have not read a proof of it because it has been omitted from my lecture notes.

Comment: You want your topological group $G$ to be abelian and compact in order for this to make sense.

Comment: @t.b. I know it wants to be locally compact for the existence of a Haar measure. And for some reason, one needs a Haar measure to do Fourier series. Why can't I just define an inner product with a different measure? And why does it have to be compact and Abelian?

Comment: When proving the basic things about the Fourier transform, you're constantly exploiting that the measure is translation invariant (e.g. $\widehat{f \ast g} = \hat{f}\hat{g}$). If $G$ is not compact you have a Fourier transform $L^2(G) \to L^2(\hat{G})$ but *no series*. In your answer you're implicitly using that on a compact group the characters belong to $L^2$ (without compactness they don't) and that they form an o.n.B  (enter commutativity). Sure, $L^2(\mu)$ and o.n. bases make sense for any measure, but they won't have much to do with $G$ as a *group* -- as opposed to a measure space.

Answer (score 4):

I doubt this statement makes sense.

What does make sense is the statement that the trigonometric polynomials ($\sin(kx), \cos(kx), k\in \mathbb{N}$ and the constant function 1) form a complete orthogonal system (orthonormal with correct normalization) of functions in $L^2([0,2\pi])$, say.

This then refers to the fact that each function in $L^2([0,2\pi])$ admits a unique representation like the one you wrote down with convergence w.r.t to the norm of $L^2$, i.e. 
$$ ||f(x) - \frac{a_0}{2} - \sum_1^n (a_n \cos (nx)+b_n \sin(nx))||_{L^2} \rightarrow 0 \,\, (n\rightarrow \infty) $$

A proof of this fact can be found in several standard texts on analysis, like e.g. Rudin's Principles of mathematical analysis.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing you *omit* the $n=5$ term from the cosine series so $a_5\cos(5\theta)$ just isn't included.  Why would the set of functions you're adding up be *incomplete*?

The point is that there would be some functions that cannot be approached by series that omit that term.  One such function is $\cos(5\theta)$ itself.

"Approached" means convergence in the $L^2$ sense, i.e. $f_n\to f$ in $L^2$ means that $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} |f_n(\theta) - f(\theta)|^2\,d\theta \to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

And "some functions" means some $L^2$ functions, i.e. functions $f$ such that $\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} |f(\theta)|^2\,d\theta<\infty$.